# I need to hide some of the parts of zf2 URL

Tags: php, url, zend-framework2, url-routing

I have a web app using zf2. And when it launches it shows the URL like follows:

1. http://www.example.com/auth/themes/neighborhoods for the neighborhoods
2. http://www.example.com/auth/comments/comments for the comments
3. http://www.example.com/auth/themes/themes for the themes

I need to make them like:

1. http://www.example.com/neighborhoods
2. http://www.example.com/comments
3. http://www.example.com/themes

I tried to play with module.config.php, but no use:

```
       'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'home' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Auth\Controller\Index',
                            'action'     => 'login',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

'auth' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/auth',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Auth\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Auth\Controller\Index',
                        'action'        => 'login',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id'         => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solution one :

```
'neighborhoods' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/neighborhoods',
        'defaults' => array(
            'module' => 'auth',
            'controller' => 'neighborhoods',
            'action' => 'neighborhoods',
        ),
     ),
     'child_routes' => array(
       'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'id'  => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     ), 
                     'defaults' => array(
                     ),
        ),
     ),
),
'comments' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/comments',
        'defaults' => array(
            'module' => 'auth',
            'controller' => 'comments',
            'action' => 'comments',
        ),
    ),
     'child_routes' => array(
       'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'id'  => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     ), 
                     'defaults' => array(
                     ),
        ),
     ),
),
'themes' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/themes',
        'defaults' => array(
            'module' => 'auth',
            'controller' => 'themes',
            'action' => 'themes',
        ),
    ),
     'child_routes' => array(
       'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'id'  => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     ), 
                     'defaults' => array(
                     ),
        ),
     ), 
),
```

Solution 2 : Custom route

http://www.zendexperts.com/2012/12/09/custom-routing-in-zend-framework-2/

in  module.config.php

```
'routeTestCustom' => array(
    'type' => 'pageRoute',
 ),
```

in Module.php

```
use [modulename]\Route\PageRoute;
....
public function getRouteConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'pageRoute' => function ($routePluginManager) {
                $locator = $routePluginManager->getServiceLocator();
                $params = array('defaults' => array('module' => 'auth' ));
                $route = PageRoute::factory($params);
                $route->setServiceManager($locator);
                return $route;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

your custom route class in [module_name]\src[module_name]\Route\PageRoute.php

```
namespace [module_name]\Route;

use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\RouteInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\RouteMatch;

class PageRoute implements RouteInterface
{
    protected $defaults;

    public function __construct(array $defaults = array())
    {
        $this->defaults = $defaults;
    }

    public static function factory($options = array())
    {
        if ($options instanceof Traversable) {
            $options = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($options);
        } elseif (!is_array($options)) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(__METHOD__ . ' expects an array or Traversable set of options');
        }

        if (!isset($options['defaults'])) {
            $options['defaults'] = array();
        }

        return new static($options['defaults']);
    }

    public function match(Request $request)
    {
        $uri  = $request->getUri();
        $path = $uri->getPath();



        $part  = explode('/',$uri);
        if(count($part) == 4 && $part[0] == 'http:' && $part[2] == "www.example.com"){
              $params = $this->defaults;
              $params['controller'] = $part[3];
              $params['action']= $part[3];
        }


        return new RouteMatch($params);
    }


    public function assemble(array $params = array(), array $options = array()){
      return $this->route;
    }

    public function getAssembledParams()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

**Updated**

Comment: you can just keep them .

Comment: you can put route file in module\[module_name]\src\[module_name]\Route\RouteTest.php and write "namespace [module_name]\Route;" . this is similar to create custom viewhelper .

Comment: excuse me for some wrong details . I update code and i think work now.

Comment: update namespace of class to  "Auth\Route" in PageRoute.php file. and "use Auth\Route\PageRoute;"  in Module.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55286/discussion-between-amin-arab-and-ginger-head).